# Initialize double array with nonzero values (BLAS)

Tags: c++, c, blas

I have allocated a big double vector, lets say with 100000 element. At some point in my code, I want to set all elements to a constant, nonzero value. How can I do this without using a for loop over all elements?
I am also using the BLAS package, if it helps.

Answer (score 10):

You could use `std::fill` (`#include <algorithm>`):

```
std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);
```

This is essentially also only a loop of course..

Comment: Except that it **may** be optimized for some particular types and iterator categories (even if it is unlikely).

Comment: I would recommend this method as well.

Answer (score 4):

'fill' is right from what you've said.

Be aware that it's also possible to construct a vector full of a specified value:

```
std::vector<double> vec(100000, 3.14);
```

So if "at some point" means "immediately after construction", do this instead. Also, it means you can do this:

```
std::vector<double>(100000, 3.14).swap(vec);
```

which might be useful if "at some point" means "immediately after changing the size", and you expect/want the vector to be reallocated ("expect" if you're making it bigger than its prior capacity, "want" if you're making it much smaller and want it trimmed to save memory).

Answer (score 1):

It is unfortunate the other answers didn't follow the prompt, the OP wanted to set the elements of an array to zero.
There could be several reason to use BLAS instead of more idiomatic functions (such as `memset` or `fill`).
For example BLAS operations could be threaded.
Also `memset` and `fill` do not offer out-of-the-box *strided* operations.

At first glance, it seems that the BLAS library doesn't offer such functionality, however, there are two options:

1. One can exploit the BLAS function `xSCAL` for that (`x` can be `s`,`d`,`c`,`z` for different numeric types).

`SCAL` does the scale operation `V <- a*V`.
For `a = 0` it sets the elements to zero (mostly).

2. Use `xCOPY`, and copy a single zero from stack memory.

Full code below.

Both approaches have their own problems, the first strategy relies on any `x*0.0 == 0.0` for any floating point number x.
Which is technically not true for `x == NAN` or `x == infinity` (both cases illustrated).
Maybe BLAS could be compiled in a non-IEEE compliant manner that in effect gives this.
In any case, if for some reason you know that the original values are regular numbers then you can use this.
Another issue is that you could get signed zeros (`-0.0`) as elements, which are ok, except that they may end up not all being the same uniform (e.g. positive zero, `0.0`).

The second is more robust but relies on BLAS accepting zero-stride values.
(BLAS was invented and coded in Fortran in the 70's, integer zero was not invented at the time.)
Most implementations I know would allow zero increments, at least, for `xCOPY`.
It also needs to pull out the "first" zero from somewhere; in this example is just created in the stack.
(If you are generalizing to GPU BLAS (cuBLAS) then you will need to allocate this zero in the GPU.)

So, in other words, you have to know your platform and the BLAS you have available.

```
#include<cstdint>
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>

extern "C" {
void sscal_(int32_t const& n, float const& a, float* x, int32_t const& incx);
void scopy_(int32_t const& n, float const* x, int32_t const& incx, float* y, int32_t const& incy);
}

void set_zero_1(int32_t n, float* x, int incx) {
  sscal_(n, 0.0F, x, incx);
}

void fill_value(int32_t n, float* x, int incx, float const* value_ptr) {
  scopy_(n, value_ptr, 0, x, incx);
}

void set_zero_2(int32_t n, float* x, int incx) {
  float const value = 0.0F;  // can also be allocated or be a global if necessary
  fill_value(n, x, incx, &value);
}

int main() {
  float X[12] = {
    99.9, 0.0, 0.0, 
    std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN(), 0.0, 0.0, 
    std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity(), 0.0, 0.0, 
    99.9, 0.0, 0.0
  };
//set_zero_1(                 4,            &X[0],            3);  // this fails because NAN and INF
  set_zero_2(/*num elements*/ 4, /*origin*/ &X[0], /*stride*/ 3);
  for(int i = 0; i != 12; i += 3) std::cout << X[i] << std::endl;  // prints zeros
}
```

use like this. It will print zeros.

```
$ c++ a.cpp -L/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2023.0.0/lib/intel64 -lmkl_rt 
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2023.0.0/lib/intel64
$ ./a.out
0
0
0
0
```

---

Bonus, there is also this way, but it relies on BLAS being sequential, and it can't parallelize or vectorized any operation for this to work, so it is probably the worst option.

```
void set_zero_3(int32_t n, float* x, int incx) {
  *x = 0.0F;  // set one element to zero, somehow. (see note above about memory that is not accessible from the CPU)
  scopy_(n - 1, x, incx, x + incx, incx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You always use `memset()` if you don't want to loop.

That is, `memset(myarr, 5, arrsize);` in order to fill it with all 5's. Beware of implicit conversion to unsigned char.

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>  #include <string.h>
>
>  void *
>  memset(void *b, int c, size_t len);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>  The memset() function writes len bytes of value c (converted to an
>  unsigned char) to the byte string b.
> ```

And if the vector is large, and you need it to go fast and you are using gcc, then :

> Code generation of block move (memcpy)
>   and block set (memset) was rewritten.
>   GCC can now pick the best algorithm
>   (loop, unrolled loop, instruction with
>   rep prefix or a library call) based on
>   the size of the block being copied and
>   the CPU being optimized for.

Comment: -1: He has a double vector and memset for a double vector (i can understand it's a contiguous array beneath vector), when he specifically wants it to be a non-zero value is not trivial. The value that can be set via memset is a byte (size of unsigned char), while the constant he wants to set is 4 bytes

Comment: Missed the double vector while reading. If he needs all 4bytes filled, then yes this won't do. On the other side, he probably wants to mark them as "unused" and one byte can do the trick.

Comment: I don't see the OP mentioning that though. But to be precise with his question I believe std::fill is his best choice.